# Obtaining bits from a byte without shifts

Tags: c, bit-shift, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I am trying to obtain a number of bits from a byte in C. Currently I am doing so by shifting and then bit masking (0xFF), however the shifting operator is taking a long time. Is there another way to this using only bitwise operations? And if so how?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you determine that the shift operator is taking a long time?  How long?  Perhaps you should show a little code sample of what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to move a particular (single) bit to the least-significant position, you can use a hack like this:

```
(x & mask) != 0
```

where `mask` selects the single bit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not.  Each of the bit positions is an independent data stream.  So long as you're restricted to these, no amount of bit-wise operation will make one bit affect any position other than its own.

Even if you allow basic arithmetic, the appropriate operations -- multiply and divide by powers of 2 -- are slower and less obvious than the shift operations.

---

To shift right N bits, divide by 2^N.
To shift left N bits, multiply by 2^N.

If the bits are in the same place every time, and you can use them where they are, then move your mask.  For instance

```
word & 0x3FC0
```

will get you bits 2-9 (or 13-6, depending on your indexing) of the word.

As before, though, I would be surprised to find that arithmetic is faster than shifting.  What platform are you using where **shift** is slow?  Most processors have this as a machine instruction.

---

Since you're not sharing details of the machine or application, about all I can suggest is to shift to the nearest byte boundary -- no more than 4 bits away -- and extract the desired value by accessing the byte.  If that still isn't a reasonable solution for you, then I'll wait for a proper problem description.

Comment: so if im using shifting to get a sequential set of bits in a byte, but the shifting operation is very expensive on the microcontroller im using, there is no other way to do it?

Comment: That's a different question.  What *exactly* is the "it" you want to do?  Merely *obtaining* a sequential set of bits is simply **and** against the corresponding mask.  Please edit your question to describe the actual problem.

Comment: Sorry for noticing so late about this comment! I edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! On this particular controller, every shift is done in 2s for e.g.  <<14 has to be done as <<2 for 7 times

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but after doing the doing the mask, how would I be able to assign a variable to that bit sequence (2 to 9)?

Comment: You grab the entire two bytes, complete with leading and trailing zeros.  If that's not what you need ... well, that's why I've been asking for specs.

Comment: I need to store bits 2-9 in a separate variable, say another byte. How would I do that?

Comment: As I said above, I suspect that your best solution is to shift the unit to the nearest boundary.  In this case, a single shift instruction puts the data in bits 0-7.  Just assign from that byte, and you're done -- no **and** with mask is needed.